# Use python to execute javascript on a given list of websites and output result to a csv

Tags: javascript, python

I have an input file which contains a list of URLs. I am trying to execute a script on each of  those URLs and output the result of that script to a CSV.

An example is trying to find if a given list of sites are using Google Analytics. The script below when run in the context of the page will return a JSON like "{'GA': true}".

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var source = [];
for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i ++) {
    var s = scripts[i];
    if (!s.src) continue;
    source.push(s.src);
}
checkforGA();


function checkforGA() {
    var tools = {};
    for (var j = 0 ; j < source.length; j ++) {
        if (/google-analytics.com\/(ga|urchin).js/i.test(source))
        {
            tools.GA = true;
            return JSON.stringify(tools);
        }
        else 
        {
            tools.GA = false;
            return JSON.stringify(tools);
        }
    }
}
```

My input is a csv file which has a list of sites

```
Google, http://google.com
Wikipedia, http://wikipedia.com
Techcrunch, http://techcrunch.com
Stackoverflow, http://stackoverflow.com
Yahoo, http://yahoo.com
```

My desired output is

```
Google, http://google.com, {'GA': false}
Wikipedia, http://wikipedia.com, {'GA': false}
Techcrunch, http://techcrunch.com, {'GA': true}
Stackoverflow, http://stackoverflow.com, {'GA': true}
Yahoo, http://yahoo.com, {'GA': false}
```

I am not sure if it is possible to run js from within a python script but i am looking for some idea on how to get started.

Comment: Do you really need this in Javascript, cause writing it in pure python will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to load the text of the page and then use the re module to search for your regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Running through HTML with RE can sometimes present problems in complicated documents.
Why don't you try using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead for something like this?It's made for it. I included an example for trying this on SO, using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) module.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

alist =  soup.find_all('script')
for script in alist:
    try:
        if script.text.find('var _gaq=_gaq') != -1:
            print 'found'
        else:
            print 'not found'
    except KeyError:
        print 'no src'
```

BTW, this methodology will not catch everything, in case of people putting their GA inits in other scripts... You may want to use Selenium to check for the presence of a '_gaq' var instead...

Comment: I was planning on using Scrapy but the problem is the stuff that i am looking for isn't always going to be in the DOM (Google Analytics was an example). I wanted a way to check window objects too. I will try if i can get it with Selenium. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @Ram PhantomJS may help too. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it all in JS - e.g. using PhantomJS - https://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/?

Comment: I think i am proceeding in the direction of doing it all in js. Looking at the script tag alone was very straight forward to do in pure python like in the comment from 'snkashis' above. I was looking at Selenium initially but phantomjs looks more like what i need. Thanks for the suggestion.